# Using PendingIntent to reach my method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications

I have an android App that makes notifications. I can generate a notification together with a button, without a problem. My problem is the button's action. I want the button to call a method, for example a text-printing method. I'm using addAction(icon, "title", pendingIntent).

```
public void sendNotification(Context context) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SomeClass.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            // This creates the button and it is using a pending intent.
            .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Print something", printPendingIntent)
            // Clicking on notification takes you back to the App.
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("My Title")
            .setContentText("Some text");

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

So the problem is in printPendingIntent, (no code written as you can see),
how do I access / call a method by using this pending intent?

Thanks for answers and sorry if the question is not clear and detailed enough.

Comment: do you want to open that activity and then perform the printing or just start printing as the user clicks the button?

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as I can connect the button to call a method (inside the class). In this example, a simple print.

Comment: it does matter if you are opening an activity for calling a function, then there will be a view and if you only want process something in background then you don't have the view for that case we use `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Ok. So in this case I don't want it to depend on an activity. I want my method to perform something in the background and I will use BroadcastReciever.

Answer (score 0):

add intent.putExtra("key","printmethod"); then receive the data in your SomeClass using getIntent().getExtras("Key"); if the value is matched then you can call your desired method in that activity.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed example please?

Comment: In your example add data to the intent like following
 Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SomeClass.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);